# GAM with negative binomial and temporal autocorrelation

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, generalized-additive-model, spatio-temporal

I want to fit a GAM in R. My data are negative binomial. Plus they have a temporal autocorrelation.

```
m1 <- gam(Y~s(X,Day), s(fDate, bs="re"), family=negbin(c(1,10), link = log), data=data)  
Resid <- resid(m1)   
acf(Resid)
```

With the `acf()` function I have detected a temporal autocorrelation. Can I apply a correlation structure in `gam()`, or do I have to use `gamm()`, since in `gamm()` I can´t use a negative binomial function, or am I doing something wrong with that? Is it basically possible to apply a negative binomial family in `gamm()` like this?

```
m2 <- gamm(Y~s(X,Day), random=list(Date=~1), family=negbin(c(1,10), link = log),
 correlation=corAR1(form=~Day), data=data)
```

Comment: I think this should stay as on topic here. There are statistical issues with estimating auto-regressive components in generalized linear models - i.e. with an exponential link function if the AR term is positive it implies a non-stationary time series. (Although I am not that familiar with `gamm` - so I am not sure what `form=~Day` means exactly in this context.) So I think it should stay here, with a discussion of possible reasonable model specifications.